# How to get jquery plug-in mmenu to jump to an element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

So below is my jade template syntax. I'm using this as to make this easier to read on Stack Overflow & for myself. My html comes out fine with the below four links being clickable in mmenu. I'm not getting any javascript errors & I'm loading both of the all css, js files that mmenu has avalible. Whenever I click on the links nothing happens on mobile. They literally don't do anything. I need them to jump to the divs that have the IDS listed. Any thoughts, ideas or support is much appreciated.

```
div(class='container-fluid noPadding mobileNavContainer') 
  nav#mobileMenu 
   ul
    li
      a(href='#home') Home
    li
      a(href='#aboutUs') About us
    li
      a(href='#gallery') Gallery
    li
      a(href='#contact') Contact
```

As far as jQuery code goes it is just the default mmenu code & the menu shows up, the dropdown works as it should etc. The problem is that my a links aren't jumping to the elements when I click on them in the mmenu.

Here's my jQuery code.

```
  $("#mobileMenu").mmenu({
         // options
      }, {
         // configuration
         offCanvas: {
           pageNodetype: "nav" 
        }
      });
   $("#mobileMenu").mmenu();
```

Comment: could you post the code you are working with ?

Comment: I updated the post with a summary at the bottom.  I'm mainly looking for some possible ideas as to why the browser doesn't go to the elements when I click on the a links. Take in mind mmenu is a jQuery plug-in. Is it normal to have issues with jumping to elements from a links with jQuery?

Comment: its really hard to find the problem without the code.

Comment: I added my jQuery code. There are no errors with my code btw. I'm literally not sure what the issue is or could possibly be. I tried using the mmenu debugger but  it doesn't show any errors or messages of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by going into the mmenu.all JS file and commenting out anything related to OnClick.